# React: should I add key to DOM or it is enough to keep it in object state?

Tags: reactjs

[For performance reason](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) and to avoid `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` key should be added to state.

It is unclear if `key` attribute should be added to DOM. For example should I add `key` to `React.createElement('li', {className: 'book'},` in:

```
var books = [
    {key: 1, author: "aaa", title: "111"},
];

var BookView = createReactClass({
    render: function() {
        return React.createElement('li', {className: 'book'},
            this.props.author,
            " - ",
            React.createElement('i', null, this.props.title))
    },
});
var BooksView = createReactClass({
    render: function () {
        return React.createElement('ul', {className: 'books'},
            this.props.data.map(function(__) { return React.createElement(BookView, __); }))
    }
});

var booksArea = document.getElementById('booksArea');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BooksView, {data: books}), booksArea);
```

Answer (score 2):

As descirbed in [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) :

> A good rule of thumb is that elements inside the map() call need keys.

So in your case its `BooksView` as you are creating a lists of elements using `.map()`

As you are already passing `key` property as a `props` to the model , that would be sufficient to satisfy the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `key` prop to the repeated element. In this case, `BookView`.

Since your model already has a key property, and you are passing that model as the props object, that should be sufficient.